# Prevent muscle decreases after injury (left arm)

Tags: exercise, muscle, injury, bodyweight-exercises

I'm a calisthenics enthusiast training towards advanced exercises like (Tuck-) Planche, Handstand Push Ups, (Ring-) Muscle Ups, Human Flag, etc. Because of a torn muscle fiber in my left forearm, I have to pause doing such exercises for at least 6 weeks. Now I am afraid of loosing muscles in my arms and shoulders. Which other exercises can I do in order to prevent muscle decreases as best as possible? Other suggestions are greatly appreciated as well!

---

**Update:** Recently, I talked to a sports student who encouraged me to do sports despite my injury. He told me it is fine (even beneficial) to load the injured muscle - provided it does not hurt - to strengthen it from the very beginning. Now, after two weeks of recovery, it actually feels okay to do some push ups or hand stands.

What do you think? Is he right that loading the muscle a bit can be beneficial for the recovery, or do you recommend to rest strictly?

Comment: If you're dealing with an injury, you should consult with a physical therapist for the correct course of action.

Comment: @rrirower: I honestly don't know how to find a therapist who is competent and interested in such questions. My doctor just told me to pause for 6 weeks - problem solved. My injury is really not a big deal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.

1. Optimize your rest- sleep well in a dark cool room and get 7-9 hours. This helps at a hormonal level (Human growth hormone and testosterone) to maintain/ build muscle.
2. load the uninjured side. I don't know the mechanism for why this works. Perhaps it is hormonal as well. You don't need to worry about an imbalance if you do this for a short period of time.
3. Visualization- spend some time vividly picturing the exercises you are training towards.
4. Eat well- you need good nutrients to repair/maintain muscle. You could also do some core strength that doesn't load the injured area (like dead bug). Get well soon :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim! I will do my best to follow your suggestions. Please note, that I updated my post. Do you have an opinion to what I added?

Comment: I am glad you liked my response. I agree with the student. Proceed with caution. Pain during is a red flag. Also, you shouldn't be waking up stiff the next day. If you get pain/ stiffness that is a sign you are doing a little too much (for early stages of an injury). I hope you get back to the fun stuff real soon :)